# Buffer to sign parameter is mandatory- Create Graphical Signature - DSA(DocuSign Signature Appliance) REST Web Services

Tags: docusignapi

Getting Error while cosuming this API(function) Create Graphical Signature

[Image Attached API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAg6N.png)
[CodeSample PostMan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTD58.png)

Comment: The minimum requirements at Stack Overflow are, that you'd post the code relevant to the issue in the question itself, and describe the problem in details. What you want your code to do, and what it does instead.

Comment: Post Editted @niklas.
Image attached for Reference

Comment: Please read the [guide on how to ask good guestions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please add your code sample and the response as text within your question, not as screenshots.

Comment: You are using "SignBuffer." There is no graphical image in buffer signing. If you want to sign on a buffer you should do it like this - {"signBuffer" :{"BufferToSign": "{{PDFFileData In Base 64}}"}}.

Answer (score 1):

To Create Graphical signature in your DSA you should use the following

```
POST https://DSA:8081/sapiws/v1/users/{{USER}}/graphical_signatures

{
    "imageName" : "The Graphical Image Name",
    "imageFile" : "The Graphical Signature Image Data In Base 64"
}
```

When {{User}} is the name of the user you want to create the graphical signature

If you want to perform sign operation, DSA Rest API allows you to sign in three different ways.

1. Buffer sign
2. Sign on a signature field
3. Create field and sign

#### Buffer sign-

```
PUT https://DSA:8081/sapiws/v1/digital_signature

{
    "signBuffer": {
        "BufferToSign": "Data"
    }
}
```

When "Data" is your data you want to sign on, it should be encoded with Base64.

#### Sign on a signature field-

```
PUT https://DSA:8081/sapiws/v1/digital_signature

{
    "signField": {
        "signatureFieldName": "The Signature Name"
                        "file": "The PDF File Data",
        "FileType": "PDF"
    }
}
```

When the PDF file data is in Base64.

You can get the signature field name by using it like this.

```
POST https://DSA:8081/sapiws/v1/digital_signature

{
    "getAllSignatureFields": {
        "file": "The Signed File",
        "FileType": "PDF",
    }
}
```

#### Create field and sign-

```
PUT https://DSA:8081/sapiws/v1/digital_signature

{
    "CreateAndSignField": {
        "file": "The PDF File Data",
        "fileType": "PDF"
    }
}
```